# Type checking on Array.map that returns object literals

Tags: typescript

I've created [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Test%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20object%3A%20Test%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20'b'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20'c'%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20testIt()%3A%20Test%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%7Bb%3A%20'2'%2C%20c%3A%20'3'%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20prices%3A%20Test%5B%5D%20%3D%20data.length%20%3F%20data.map((item)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3A%20item.b%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%3A%20item.c%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3A%20'2'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d%3A%20'3'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%20%3A%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20prices%3B%0D%0A%7D) in the TypeScript playground:

```
interface Test{
    a: string
    b: string
}

const object: Test = {
    a: 'b',
    b: 'c',
}

function testIt(): Test[] {
    const data = [{b: '2', c: '3'}]
    const prices: Test[] = data.length ? data.map((item) => {
        return {
            a: item.b,
            b: item.c,
            c: '2',
            d: '3'
        }
    }) : [];
    return prices;
}
```

Removing either a or b property from the object return statement in the array map method results in a TypeScript error (as expected).

Adding c or d or any other random unknown property does not trigger a TypeScript error. I would suspect that this is only possible if the interface contains [x: string]: any.

So why does Array.map do type checking on missing properties on an interface but not on additional / unknown properties?

Comment: Because to match an interface you have to implement everything it declares. But you can have additional method/properties it still match the required implementation.

Comment: That's wrong. If you add `c: 'test'` to the const object from above example, you would still get the error. For dynamic properties, you need to add [x: string]: any;. But in this case not in Array.map, which is the thing I find weird.

Comment: That's because you are using an object literal in this case typescript doesn't allow unknown properties from base type. In the map function you let typescript infer the type that's why it's working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that according to basic OOP rules, a derived type (ie one with more properties) should be compatible with the base type (ie. the type with just `a` and `b`).

This being said, typescript does warn us when assigning object literals with more properties where a type with fewer properties is expected. This is called excess property checking. This feature only kicks in on DIRECT assignment to something that is o a given type.

The reason this excess property check does not apply in your case is the way type checking is done for `map`. First the callback return type is inferred based on the object literal, so it is inferred as `{ a: string, b: string, c: string, d: string }`. Then this type is used as the return type for `map`, so `map` will return an `Array<{ a: string, b: string, c: string, d: string }>`. This is then assigned to `Test[]` which under the first rule is allowed. Nowhere did we assign an object literal to a place where `Test` was expected.

One way to get an error is to not let typescript infer the result of callback passed to `map`. We can do this by adding the annotation to the callback. Then we are directly assigning an object literal to a location that expects `Test`:

```
const prices = data.length ? data.map((item) : Test => {
    return {
        a: item.b,
        b: item.c,
        c: '2', // error
        d: '3'
    }
}) : [];
```

Comment: I would expect that `data.map` implicitly returns `Array<{ a: string, b: string, c: string, d: string }>`, which does not match `Test[]`. Still data.map is smart enough to figure out missing properties. Why not do a full exact type check? I mean, in what use case would you want this behavior?

Comment: @KeesvanLierop Why wouldn't it mach ? Allowing the assignment, can you do anything on `Test[]` that would be invalid on `Array<{ a: string, b: string, c: string, d: string }>` ? `{ a: string, b: string, c: string, d: string }` is derived from `Test` under the structural type system TS uses, so you are assigning an array of a derived object to an array of a base object.

Comment: @KeesvanLierop  you can read more in the docs : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html under excess property

Comment: Please accept as correct answer and thanks @TitianCernicova-Dragomir !